# SVG Path animation with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to animate SVG->Path element.

It is like a timer, in 10 seconds, it should be zero

[image: svg circle]

This is my SVG codes:

```
<div style="margin:200px">
    <svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
        <path transform="translate(75, 75) scale(1)" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)" d="M 0, 0 V -75 A 75 75 1 1 1 -0.001 -75 Z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

But I have no idea how to start to animate it by jQuery

Comment: A similar example can be found here, in pure js+DOM, no jQuery necessary: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/clippath/animated-clippath-arc.svg.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Thanks for your reply Erik, How can I make it clockwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do this without using jQuery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 480 360" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Animates a path</title>  
    <path id="arc" d="M0 0"/>
    <script> 
        var circle = document.getElementById("arc"),
            startangle = -90,
            angle = startangle,
            radius = 100,
            cx = 240,
            cy = 180,
            increment = 5; // make this negative to animate counter-clockwise

        function drawCircle() {
            var radians = (angle/180) * Math.PI,
                x = cx + Math.cos(radians) * radius,
                y = cy + Math.sin(radians) * radius,
                e = circle.getAttribute("d"),
                d = "";

            if(angle == startangle)
                d = "M "+cx + " " + cy + "L "+x + " " + y;
            else
                d = e + " L "+x + " " + y;

            circle.setAttribute("d", d);

            angle += increment;
            if (Math.abs(angle) > (360+startangle*Math.sign(increment)))
                angle = startangle;

            window.requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);
        }

        drawCircle();
</script>
</svg>
```

See [live example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/path/animated-circle.svg).

Comment: Your live example only runs in firefox. in IE and Chrome it doesn't show anything